# Remove #about from url after clicking close

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a button that displays an overlay on click with Javascript to a url like this:

http://www.sample.com/#about

However the close button I have will just remove the overlay and not the `/#about` part in the url. What is the best way to remove the `/#about` when clicking the close button?

HTML

```
    <button id="hide" class="close">&#10060</button>
```

JS

```
// Simple show and hide button
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#about").fadeOut();
});
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("#about").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Do you want the `#about` hash to exist when the user clicks on `#show`?

Comment: I edited my answer. Seems like notifications don't work properly.

Comment: @Rob I posted an answer that doesn't allow the `#about` to appear at all. Since it has no use for you, I think it's better not to let it appear at all than trying to remove it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following javscript:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#about").fadeOut();
    window.location.hash="";
});
```

`#about` is the hash of page. script about will just remove it.

**EDIT:**

If you can use HTML5 features you can do the following (it will remove the "#" too):

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#about").fadeOut();
    history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
});
```

Comment: It still seems to keep the # there in the url, any ideas on how to remove it also?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want the `#about` hash to exist at all, you could add the `return false` statement at the end of each handler function.

For example:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#about").fadeOut();
    return false;
});
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("#about").fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```